# Show a text in center location before an image

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:-

```html
<hr>
    <div style='display:flex;align-items:center'>
    <span style=''><b>Device and Operating System Selection</b></span>
    <img style='height:200px;width:120px'src='https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/HomeOffice/en-ca/Forms/SiteAssets/bc756161-82b9-4c40-ae98-e73d54597cbe.jpg'/><br/>
    </div>
    We offer 2 types of devices
```

where the result will be as follow:-

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

while i am trying to show the text in the middle of the picture and not on top of item , as follow:-

Comment: Consider to use figcaption instead using span [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)

Comment: you want same thing as your image right?

Comment: @Diwyansh i want the text to be show in the middle not in the bottom of the picture.. check my edit

Comment: i've insert your code into the SO snippet and the output is the desired result....

Comment: @Sfili_81 where?

Comment: you can check the updated one

Comment: check my question edit

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change add `justify-content: center;`
that will align the text in center vertically.
`align-items:center;` is to align the items center horizontally.

```html
<div style='display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content: center;'>
        <span style=''><b>Device and Operating System Selection</b></span>
        <img style='height:200px;width:120px'
            src='https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/HomeOffice/en-ca/Forms/SiteAssets/bc756161-82b9-4c40-ae98-e73d54597cbe.jpg' /><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: using `flex-direction:column` did not have any effect in my case

Comment: to align it center vertically use `justify-content: center;`, it will work fyn.

Comment: `justify-content: center; `did not work eiter

Comment: did you add `justify-content: center; ` in the div ?

Answer (score -1):

Easy ;D

```html
<hr>
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;">
  <span><b>Device and Operating System Selection</b></span>
  <img style="height:200px;width:120px" src="https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/HomeOffice/en-ca/Forms/SiteAssets/bc756161-82b9-4c40-ae98-e73d54597cbe.jpg"><br>
</div>
We offer 2 types of devices
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure @Sfili_81 I'll edit

Comment: @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t i want the text to be show in the middle not in the bottom of the picture.. check my edit

Comment: @johnGu Updated answer

Answer (score -2):

you can assign align-self style to your span

```
<div style='display:flex;align-items:center'>
<span style='align-self:center; margin-right:10px;'><b>Device and Operating System Selection</b></span>
<img style='height:200px;width:120px'src='https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/products/large/iqoo-3-db-386x800-1582613523.jpg'/><br/>
</div>
We offer 2 types of devices
```

[image]

Comment: i want the text to be show in the middle not in the bottom of the picture.. check my edit

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: did not work in my case

Comment: I have used same code as yours and attached screenshot also then how could it be possible?  it means you are not using the same code?